# Using join points call(* *.*(..)), can I expose the arguments to the advice if available?

Tags: java, refactoring, aspectj, pointcut

With my aspect, I track the changes on certain collections by advising certain method calls on instances of `java.util.Set`, notably `add(Object)` and `remove(Object)`. Since the changes are not reflected in the collection itself, invocations of `Set.contains(Object)` or `Set.size()` return wrong results.

Therefore I want to intercept all method calls to instances of Set (except `add` and `remove`), and forward the calls to my up-to-date collection.

Of course I could define two advices, using different pointcuts, something like this:

```
// matches Collection.size(), Collection.isEmpty(), ...
* around(Collection c) : call(* Collection.*()) && target(c)
            && !remove(/*...*/) && !add(/*...*/) {
    if (notApplicable())
        return proceed(c);

    return proceed(getUpToDateCollection());
}

// matches Collection.contains(Object), ...
* around(Collection c, Object arg) : call(* Collection.*(*)) && target(c) && args(arg) 
            && !remove(/*...*/) && !add(/*...*/) {
    if (notApplicable())
        return proceed(c, arg);

    return proceed(getUpToDateCollection(), arg);
}
```

It works, but it's pretty ugly, the bodies of my advices being quite analogous. So I would like to "combine" them; effectively having a single advice that be woven for both pointcuts, much like this:

```
* around(Object[] args): call(* Collection.*(..)) && args(arr) {...}`
```

Is this possible at all? I have the feeling it's not, because in one of the pointcuts I expose the argument (and subsequently use it in the advice) and in the other there is no argument, so it seems impossible to bind the "potential identifier" in the enclosing advice... But I'm hoping that I've overlooked something and you might be able to point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just for the record.
it *is* possible to write a pointcut which exposes an argument, and then use this pointcut in advice which doesn't access these argument parameter. Instead of writing the pointcut expression immediately into the advice definition, I'd allways prefer to define the pointcut explicitly, referring to it from the advice just by the pointcut's name (and arguments)

Comment: I do not understand this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this question has popped up in my feed as "new" after so many years, but it is still unanswered, so I will answer:

- Your assumption is correct, you cannot use `args()` in order to bind a non-existent argument.
- You could, if you absolutely want to have a single advice body, use `JoinPoint.getArgs(..)`, but it would be ugly (as in involving loops and casts) and potentially slower than having two pointcuts. A too broad pointcut would also potentially match too many joinpoints if done wrong.
- My advice - no pun intended - is to actually factor out duplicate code into helper methods and call those from both AspectJ advices. Maybe those helper methods also need a `ProceedingJoinPoint` parameter in order to call `proceed()` upon it if you also want to factor out that part. But think about readability, too. It always depends on your concrete case.

I could answer in a more concrete way (with aspect code) if your code was actually a litte [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).